# How to add a custom control to the TinyMce 4 toolbar

Tags: plugins, controls, tinymce-4

I want to introduce a new `Control` to TinyMce that I can use in the toolbar. In my case I want to add an icon control that can be placed at the start of the toolbar to differentiate between editors.

However there is almost no information about how to properly do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to come up with a way to properly do this.

First I introduce a new plugin `icon` (*in `icon/plugin.js`*) that registers a new control `Icon`. It uses a setting `iconClass`.

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('icon', function() {
    tinymce.ui.Icon = tinymce.ui.Widget.extend({
        renderHtml: function () {
            return '<span class="icon icon-' + this.settings.iconClass + '"> </span>';
        }
    });
});
```

Next I add a *button* `facebook` to the toolbar in the following way:

```
editor.addButton('facebook', {
    type: 'icon',
    iconClass: 'facebook-share'
});
```

Now I can add it to the toolbar specification:

```
tinymce.init({
    toolbar: "facebook"
})
```

That's it! The new custom control should not render. The plugin code is only ran once; even if used multiple times.

Comment: "Finally?" `asked 4 mins ago` --> `answered 4 minutes ago`!

Comment: :) I tried to solve this problem a half year ago. Today I tried to solve it again and failed again. So I was in the process of asking this question when I got the answer.